# How to turn off autocomplete=off?

Tags: html, opera

How can I configure my browser (Opera) to ignore any autocomplete=off attributes and provide autocompletion (and password saving btw.) anyways?

Comment: I know there are some plugins in chrome that can do that. I cannot seem to find any for Opera. Have you searched any? If yes update it on your question. Also what have you tried so far?

Comment: Actually, I searched for a way to set autocomplete=off to be ignored before (and not only one time) but the web is spammed on ways how to get autocomplete=off to work, not the other way round, and so the (to me) obvious search terms didn't reveal any solution. This this question and answer, this will probably change now ;)  [it's like search for »ignore autocomplete=off« reveals posts »I have autocomplete=off, but the browser ignores it«.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this website](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/opera-flags-better-browsing-experience/):

> 11. Force Autofill
>
> Some online forms prevent Autofill feature of your browser so you have to input all the data manually. It’s a good security measure, but very annoying as well. You can force Opera to autocomplete such forms using one of the flags.
>
> Enable the flag “Autofill HTML forms even if the ‘autocomplete’ attribute is set to ‘off‘” to enable this feature.
>
> Autofill HTML forms even if the ‘autocomplete’ attribute is set to ‘off’: (opera://flags/#enable-autofill-ignore-autocomplete-off)

There are some other interesting flags as well mentioned in the link

---

If that doesn't work you can download the [Download Chrome Extension](https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/download-chrome-extension-9/) and use one of the [Force Autocomplete](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/force-autocomplete/piechbhjioolbecaioglhamjjjkmbchj?hl=en) or [Always Autocomplete](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/always-autocomplete/djcfppnajkeijjkplclmeiddkefeaiel?hl=en) extensions. Chrome and Opera are based on the same platform (chromium) and as such, Opera can easily run most Chrome extensions.

> Note: I am not affiliated with the above extensions nor tested them myself.

Comment: I didn't restart Opera yet (it said, this change would take effect only after restart), but since there actually is an option for it (hidden so ideally nobody finds it ...) I guess that will work. I'll mark your question anyways, even if it doesn't work, than it's a bug in Opera and not a wrong answer.

Comment: @BodoThiesen Well it is like the developer options in android. Hidden and amazing. Since Opera has implemented themselves an option to do it in their settings it should be able to work. Now I can't say for sure that it will work 100% cause maybe some websites found a way to block this as well. However, these are the two options available. The third one (through inspect mode) doesn't usually work